# Why is DriveFile openContents intermittently resulting in failures?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

My Android application is able to Google Drive to pick a file.  After a file is selected, the result is given back to my application's `onActivityResult` and I am able to get a `DriveId`.  So far so good.

When I try to open this file, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.  In other words, `contentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()` is sometimes true and sometimes false.

The `getStatus()` has nothing indicating why it failed and there is no pending resolution.

Looking at the Android logcat, I see this message that appears to be related to the problem.  It's not from my app:

```
  E/FileDownloader﹕ Error downloading: EntrySpec[769]
    java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code: 403
        at com.google.android.gms.drive.metadata.sync.syncadapter.a.f.a(SourceFile:232)
        at com.google.android.gms.drive.metadata.sync.syncadapter.a.f.a(SourceFile:69)
        at com.google.android.gms.drive.metadata.sync.syncadapter.a.g.run(SourceFile:344)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
```

The trouble is that this is inconsistent.  Some files open and some don't.

It's not related to the files I'm opening; if I restart the app, the same erroring file will start working and others will fail. I've also gone into the API Console and increased the quota for this API to 100 requests/user/second.

Now to supplement the question, here is how I try to open the file:

```
DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient, driveId);
file.openContents(mGoogleApiClient,DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY,null)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.ContentsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.ContentsResult contentsResult) {
                    if (!contentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Could not open Google Drive file");
                        if (contentsResult.getStatus().getResolution() != null) {
                            //There is never a resolution
                            }
                        return;
                        }
                 }
                 ...
```

Comment: What is the status code and message?

Comment: It's simply: `Unexpected response code: 403` (first block of errors in the post above).  That's not appearing as part of my own application's logs, so I can't see anything beyond that.

Comment: Same error for me...

Answer (score 0):

From the description, this sounds like you've been hitting rate-limit errors while trying to make API calls. Although you might not be reaching your quota limit per day you can still be hitting your quota-per-second limit. Try fixing your quota-per-second limit from the developer console for the Drive API and also, implementing [Exponential Backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors) algorithm. This should take care of the 403 errors you are experiencing as shown in the above link.